# UITableView,unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c

I created a TableView as a subview of one UIView(call it UIViewA), and this UIView is also a subview of the main ViewController. When I tried to implement the function "`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`" of the Tableview, the program crashed with the information "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

The Delegate of the tableView is set to "file's owner" which is UIViewA.
I also tried to add some exception breakpoints but it showed that the Exception points is

> return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,
>   NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

which is in `main.m`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom table view, this should be a subclass of `UITableView`. Instead you are actually creating a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Obviously `UIViewController` has no method named `didSelectRowAtindexPath` (and I suppose neither your `UIViewA` has it). That's the cause of the crash.

[Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)